# Recommended browser window resize add-on for Firefox?

Tags: firefox, cross-platform

Can anybody recommend an add-on which works well with current (as of 2017) versions of Firefox to let you resize your browser window to a range of preferred sizes?

(I am ideally looking for an add-on as this is an OS-neutral solution, or, if it should be an appropriate alternative, a suitable helper program that would work to provide similar window sizing functionality for Linux and/or MacOS.)

The well-known [Firesizer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/firesizer/) add-on unfortunately requires an additional add-on to provide an add-on toolbar, as the Firefox developers unfortunately removed that functionality, to the annoyance of many users.

[Firesize](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/firesize/) seems to be a fairly nice alternative, but unfortunately it seems to work a little erratically and requires delving deep into add-on preferences to add new custom window sizes rather than being able to do so quickly and easily via its toolbar icon.

Thanks for any useful suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The add-on **Browsizer** seems to be exactly what you are looking for

https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/browsizer/

Comment: I have now tried this add-on and it seems to be working quite nicely with Firefox 45. (Thanks.)

Comment: Nice to hear. But why 45? We're already at 51.0.1. Running outdated browsers (and software in general) is a security risk.

Comment: Sorry, I omitted the important three letters ESR that probably should have been in "Firefox 45 ESR". I only mentioned the version number as a confirmation that the add-on worked in a recent Firefox (because too many Firefox add-ons have sadly stopped working in more recent Firefox versions, as Firefox's now too-fast "new features" relentless release schedule (bug/security fixes are important, but "features" really can wait) seems to have overwhelmed far too many add-on developers, who, despite being among the biggest fans and proponents of Firefox don't always have the spare time to keep up).

Comment: Oh... I got you!