# Browser window resizing add-on for Firefox Quantum?

Tags: firefox, cross-platform, shell-extension

Can anyone recommend an add-on for Firefox Quantum which will let you resize the browser window to a new size, from a list of sizes which you can define?

Up until now, with Firefox ESR (pre-Quantum), I had been using the very useful [Browsizer add-on](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/38998/recommended-browser-window-resize-add-on-for-firefox), but [Browsizer is not compatible with Firefox Quantum](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/browsizer/), and no longer appears to be maintained, unfortunately.

Requirements:

- Must be able to define an indefinite number of window sizes (*at least 8:* many of the WebExtension add-ons which I have found so far seem to only allow a maximum of 4 window sizes to be defined)
- Must let you access the settings for the add-on via its toolbar button (so that you can easily add/remove/edit the list of sizes without having to open the Add-ons Manager)

Desirable:

- Would be useful to be able to also set a window position for a particular window size setting (but this must be an optional setting, as there are only certain occasions where I do want to both resize and reposition a window)

Answer (score 1):

[Window Resizer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/window-resizer-webextension/#&gid=1&pid=3) works well (just tested it with Firefox 61) and allows you to define custom layouts with screen position (top, left, width, height). I don't think screen position is optionnal though.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did come across that one, but unfortunately the fact that you always have to set the window position as well as the size means that it was not quite what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some searching on https://addons.mozilla.org/ (which now seems to return better search results than it used to).

The add-on which appears to best meet my requirements *so far* seems to be **ResizeIT**, which allows window positions to be optionally set, as well as window sizes to be defined.

Unfortunately ResizeIT only allows you to define 4 window size options, however, so is not quite ideal for me.

- [ResizeIT add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/resizeit/)

There is also **WindowSizer**, which allows more than 4 resize options, but does not allow window positions to be (optionally) set. It also has a mildly annoying requirement that you give each defined size a title.

- [WindowSizer add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/windowsizer/)